# Jittering points horizontally within a grouped scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have grouped data which I would like to graph as a grouped scatter plot. Here is the data

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:46, each = 3),
                 bevType = rep(c("water","decaf","coffee"), times = 46),
                 score = c(2.9,1.0,0.0,9.5,5.0,4.5,9.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,3.0,9.5,2.0,3.0,8.5,0.0,6.0,5.2,3.0,4.0,8.4,7.0,2.0,10.0,0.0,3.0,7.3,1.0,1.8,8.5,2.0,9.0,10.0,5.0,10.0,8.3,2.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,10.0,0.0,5.0,6.8,1.0,4.8,8.0,1.0,4.0,7.0,4.0,6.0,6.5,1.0,3.1,9.0,1.0,0.0,6.0,0.0,2.0,9.5,4.0,6.0,8.0,1.0,3.8,0.4,0.0,7.0,7.0,0.0,3.0,9.0,2.0,5.0,9.5,2.0,7.0,7.9,5.0,4.9,8.0,1.0,1.0,9.3,5.0,7.9,6.5,2.0,3.0,8.0,2.0,6.0,10.0,0.0,5.0,6.0,0.0,5.0,6.8,0.1,7.0,8.0,3.0,9.1,8.2,0.0,7.9,8.2,5.0,0.0,9.2,1.0,3.1,9.1,3.0,0.6,5.7,2.0,5.1,7.0,0.0,7.4,8.0,1.0,1.5,9.1,4.0,4.3,8.5,8.0,5.0))
```

Now in order to get the dots from each group to separate out nicely into columns we have to specify a `position = position_dodge()` argument inside the `geom_jitter` function

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = bevType, colour = bevType)) +
       geom_jitter(aes(y = score), shape = 1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9))  +
       scale_colour_manual(name = "Beverage Type", labels = c("Water", "Decaf", "Coffee"), values = c("#616a6b", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +  
       labs(y = "Score", x = "Beverage Type") +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
             legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

But if I add an `width =` argument to make the points jitter sideways,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = bevType, y = score, colour = bevType)) +
       geom_jitter(shape = 1, position = position_dodge(width=0.9), width = 0.1)  +
       scale_colour_manual(name = "Beverage Type", labels = c("Water", "Decaf", "Coffee"), values = c("#616a6b", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +  
       labs(y = "Score", x = "Beverage Type") +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
             axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
             legend.title = element_blank())
```

But i get the error

```
Error: Specify either `position` or `width`/`height`
```

So I gather the two `width=` arguments in the `geom_jitter()`function are causing confusion, so **how do I jitter the points within each column horizontally?**

Comment: The `width = ` argument to `position_dodge()` is concerned with how columns are aligned, not the width of individual columns. The latter is an argument to `geom_jitter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `position_dodge()`. Just specify an appropriate width in `geom_jitter()`.  For example:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(bevType, score, colour = bevType)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 1, width = 0.2) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Beverage Type", 
                      labels = c("Water", "Decaf", "Coffee"), 
                      values = c("#616a6b", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +  
  labs(y = "Score", 
       x = "Beverage Type") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]